# Matlab integration issue, issue with input function

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to do a numerical integration on a function which is absolutely horrible to expand and work with analytically. The integral is over dpsi and dtheta. If I store the variables as sym i am told the integral input must be a double or single, if i store it as a double or single i am told I am adding two tensors of different dimensions. Help?

```
eta = input('Enter Dielectric Constant 1.5-4:  ');
psi = input('Enter Lattitude -pi/2 to +pi/2:  ');
theta = input('Enter Longitude -pi/2 to +pi/2:  ');
sdev = input('Enter STD DEV (roughness) maybe 0.1:  ');



dpsi = sym('dspi');
dtheta = sym('dtheta');

calpha = (cos(theta+dtheta)).*(cos(psi+dpsi));
rp01 = calpha-sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2));
rp02 = calpha+sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2));
rperp = (rp01./rp02).^2;
rp11 = ((eta.*calpha)-sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2)));
rp12 = ((eta.*calpha)+sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2)));
rpar = (rp11./rp12).^2;



fun = @(dtheta,dpsi) (rpar+rperp)
thetamax = (pi/2) - theta
psimax = (pi/2) - psi

q = integral2(fun,-pi/2,thetamax,-pi/2,psimax)
```

Comment: You could also use the symbolic integral to integrate symbolic expressions. Check `doc sym/int` for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simplest solution:

Convert the symbolic expression to an actual numerical function using:

```
fun = matlabFunction((rpar+rperp),'vars',{dtheta,dpsi});
```

### Better solution:

Avoid the symbolic stuff in the first place and just define a function:

```
function out = YOURFANCYFUNCTION(eta,psi,theta,sdev,dtheta,dpsi)
calpha = (cos(theta+dtheta)).*(cos(psi+dpsi));
rp01 = calpha-sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2));
rp02 = calpha+sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2));
rperp = (rp01./rp02).^2;
rp11 = ((eta.*calpha)-sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2)));
rp12 = ((eta.*calpha)+sqrt(eta-1+((calpha).^2)));
rpar = (rp11./rp12).^2;
out = (rpar+rperp);
```

The function you pass to integral should then be:

```
fun = @(dtheta,dpsi) YOURFANCYFUNCTION(eta,psi,theta,sdev,dtheta,dpsi)
```

Which captures the current values of `eta,psi,theta,sdev` and makes `dtheta` and `dpsi` variables.

By the way: The variable `sdev` is never used.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and got the result

    Function definitions are not permitted in this context.

Am I missing something subtle? Also in answer to your point sdev was from earlier code, it will be used later, but i thought i'd solve the simple problems first.

Your simplest solution fixes the problem. Do you have a reference that I could look into that would walk you through these kind of things, that I could refer to in times of trouble?

Comment: @user2720867: You will have to save the `YOURFANCYFUNCTION` in a separate file.

Comment: Well, I only know the [MATLAB docs](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) and [google](http://google.com). The documentation has great examples explaining the functionality and most of the times is quite helpful.